# How to add IP Address and userId to log file (Commons-logging lib)

Tags: java, log4j

What is the appoarch/mechanism to add IP address and Loggedin userId while logging to lof file.(using some patterns).

FYI And we are using commons-logging framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use MDC(Mapped Diagnostic Context) for doing such things. I believe you have a web application; You can configure a servlet filter which reads the IP address and user id from the servlet request and dumps it in MDC. Then your logger automatically picks this value and prints it in all the logged lines. You can refer http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/effective-logging-in-javajee-mapped-diagnostic-context.html and http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html to get an understanding of MDC

Comment: I heard about MDC but problem I see is, I need to set the MDC variable before every log statement (atleast to every method which contains log statements). Is there generic way to set these variables so that it is applicable to every log statments across the application?

Comment: Moreover, I am using commons-logging framework, is there any thing similar to MDC in this framework?

Comment: Simple log4j framework provide features to achieve this using MDC. Thanks Karthik.